# Responsive Navbar: Menu Not Disappearing (CSS and JS)

Tags: javascript, css, navbar

Building a responsive menu bar. The problem is when you click the hamburger lines and the page options appear, when you click the links, the menu doesn't disappear. I've tried adding and removing a class disappear{display:none}, and I've also tried building a for loop but neither works. I know I'm way overthinking this, what options should I explore to fix it?

(Note that you may have to shrink your screen down to less than 600px in width to see the hamburger menu if it isn't currently available to click)

lkl;

```js
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('nav_check');
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('nav_icon');

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  if(!menuBtn.classList.contains("open")){
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
  }else{
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  }
});


document.getElementsByClassName('.links').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    document.getElementById('nav_check').checked = false;
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background:#d3d3d3;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height:3.3rem;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #0A2463;
  position: fixed;
  color:#fafafa;
}

.nav_btn {
  display:none;
}

.nav_links > a {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fafafa;
}

.nav_links > a:hover {
  color:#ED1250;
}

#nav_check, #nav_icon {
  display: none;
}

.resume{
  color:#ED1250;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:solid #ED1250 1px;
  padding:.5rem;
  margin-right:.5rem;
}

.resume:hover {
  background:rgb(237, 18, 80,.2);
  color:#fafafa;
}

.social{
  display:none;
}


@media (max-width:600px) {
 .navBar{
   height:3.3rem;
  }
  
.nav_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
  }

#nav_icon{
  display:block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  right:1rem;
  top:-3rem;
  margin: 50px auto;
  z-index:6;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  border:solid orange 2px;
}

  #nav_icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(2),#nav_icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
  
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:400;
  line-height:4.5rem;
  font-size:3rem;
  background:#0A2463;
} 

.menu_textWrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column !important;
    width:18rem;
    background:#0A2463;
  }  

.links:hover::after{
  content:"»";
  font-size:2.5rem;
  }
  
#nav_check:not(:checked) ~ menu {
    display:none;
  }
  
.navBar > #nav_check:checked ~ .menu {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  
  
}/*closing bracket for media query*/
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav_check">
  <div class="nav_btn">
    <label for="nav_check" class="hamburgerLines" id="nav_icon">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="menu_textWrapper"> 
    <div class="nav_links">
      <a href="#about" class="links">About</a>
      <a href="#projects" class="links">Projects</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a>
      <a href="/resume.pdf" target="_blank"><span class="resume">Resume</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>   
 </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem was using `getElementsByClassName` like this `document.getElementsByClassName('.links').forEach` you can not use `forEach` and `.linke` css selector with `getElementsByClassName` use `querySelectorAll`

```js
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('nav_check');
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('nav_icon');

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  if(!menuBtn.classList.contains("open")){
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
  }else{
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  }
});


document.querySelectorAll('.links').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    document.getElementById('nav_check').checked = false;
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background:#d3d3d3;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height:3.3rem;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #0A2463;
  position: fixed;
  color:#fafafa;
}

.nav_btn {
  display:none;
}

.nav_links > a {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fafafa;
}

.nav_links > a:hover {
  color:#ED1250;
}

#nav_check, #nav_icon {
  display: none;
}

.resume{
  color:#ED1250;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:solid #ED1250 1px;
  padding:.5rem;
  margin-right:.5rem;
}

.resume:hover {
  background:rgb(237, 18, 80,.2);
  color:#fafafa;
}

.social{
  display:none;
}


@media (max-width:600px) {
 .navBar{
   height:3.3rem;
  }
  
.nav_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
  }

#nav_icon{
  display:block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  right:1rem;
  top:-3rem;
  margin: 50px auto;
  z-index:6;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  border:solid orange 2px;
}

  #nav_icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(2),#nav_icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
  
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:400;
  line-height:4.5rem;
  font-size:3rem;
  background:#0A2463;
} 

.menu_textWrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column !important;
    width:18rem;
    background:#0A2463;
  }  

.links:hover::after{
  content:"»";
  font-size:2.5rem;
  }
  
#nav_check:not(:checked) ~ menu {
    display:none;
  }
  
.navBar > #nav_check:checked ~ .menu {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  
  
}/*closing bracket for media query*/
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav_check">
  <div class="nav_btn">
    <label for="nav_check" class="hamburgerLines" id="nav_icon">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="menu_textWrapper"> 
    <div class="nav_links">
      <a href="#about" class="links">About</a>
      <a href="#projects" class="links">Projects</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a>
      <a href="/resume.pdf" target="_blank"><span class="resume">Resume</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>   
 </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

- when using `getElementsByClassName` you shouldn't use `.` while specifying the class.
- `getElementsByClassName` returns `HTMLCollection` that doesn't have `forEach` loop, so you need to convert it into `array` as:

`const linksArray = [...links];`
**or**
`const linksArray = Array.from( links );`

- You can also use `querySelectorAll(".links")`

```js
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById("nav_check");
const menuBtn = document.getElementById("nav_icon");

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!menuBtn.classList.contains("open")) {
    menuBtn.classList.add("open");
  } else {
    menuBtn.classList.remove("open");
  }
});

const links = document.getElementsByClassName("links");
const linksArray = [...links];

linksArray.forEach((item) => {
  item.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    document.getElementById("nav_check").checked = false;
    menuBtn.classList.remove("open");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 3.3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0A2463;
  position: fixed;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.nav_btn {
  display: none;
}

.nav_links>a {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin: auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fafafa;
}

.nav_links>a:hover {
  color: #ED1250;
}

#nav_check,
#nav_icon {
  display: none;
}

.resume {
  color: #ED1250;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: solid #ED1250 1px;
  padding: .5rem;
  margin-right: .5rem;
}

.resume:hover {
  background: rgb(237, 18, 80, .2);
  color: #fafafa;
}

.social {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .navBar {
    height: 3.3rem;
  }
  .nav_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
  }
  #nav_icon {
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 45px;
    position: fixed;
    right: 1rem;
    top: -3rem;
    margin: 50px auto;
    z-index: 6;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: solid orange 2px;
  }
  #nav_icon span {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 9px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fafafa;
    border-radius: 9px;
    opacity: 1;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
    transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  }
  #nav_icon span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0px;
  }
  #nav_icon span:nth-child(2),
  #nav_icon span:nth-child(3) {
    top: 18px;
  }
  #nav_icon span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 36px;
  }
  #nav_icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  #nav_icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  #nav_icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
  #nav_icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
    top: 18px;
    width: 0%;
    left: 50%;
  }
  .menu {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 4.5rem;
    font-size: 3rem;
    background: #0A2463;
  }
  .menu_textWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    width: 18rem;
    background: #0A2463;
  }
  .links:hover::after {
    content: "»";
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  #nav_check:not(:checked)~menu {
    display: none;
  }
  .navBar>#nav_check:checked~.menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}


/*closing bracket for media query*/
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav_check">
  <div class="nav_btn">
    <label for="nav_check" class="hamburgerLines" id="nav_icon">
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
            </label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menu_textWrapper">
      <div class="nav_links">
        <a href="#about" class="links">About</a>
        <a href="#projects" class="links">Projects</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a>
        <a href="/resume.pdf" target="_blank"><span class="resume">Resume</span></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const toggleBtn = document.getElementById('nav_check');
const menuBtn = document.getElementById('nav_icon');

toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){ 
  if(!menuBtn.classList.contains("open")){
    menuBtn.classList.add('open');
  }else{
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  }
});
[].forEach.call( document.getElementsByClassName('links'), item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    document.getElementById('nav_check').checked = false;
    menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
  })
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background:#d3d3d3;
}

.navBar {
  width: 100%;
  height:3.3rem;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  align-items:center;
  background-color: #0A2463;
  position: fixed;
  color:#fafafa;
}

.nav_btn {
  display:none;
}

.nav_links > a {
  padding: .5rem;
  margin:auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  color:#fafafa;
}

.nav_links > a:hover {
  color:#ED1250;
}

#nav_check, #nav_icon {
  display: none;
}

.resume{
  color:#ED1250;
  border-radius:4px;
  border:solid #ED1250 1px;
  padding:.5rem;
  margin-right:.5rem;
}

.resume:hover {
  background:rgb(237, 18, 80,.2);
  color:#fafafa;
}

.social{
  display:none;
}


@media (max-width:600px) {
 .navBar{
   height:3.3rem;
  }
  
.nav_btn {
    display: inline-block;
    float:right;
  }

#nav_icon{
  display:block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 45px;
  position: fixed;
  right:1rem;
  top:-3rem;
  margin: 50px auto;
  z-index:6;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  border:solid orange 2px;
}

  #nav_icon span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 9px;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fafafa;
  border-radius: 9px;
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: .25s ease-in-out;
  transition: .25s ease-in-out;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 0px;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(2),#nav_icon span:nth-child(3) {
  top: 18px;
}

#nav_icon span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 36px;
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(1) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

#nav_icon.open span:nth-child(4) {
  top: 18px;
  width: 0%;
  left: 50%;
}
  
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display:none;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  font-weight:400;
  line-height:4.5rem;
  font-size:3rem;
  background:#0A2463;
} 

.menu_textWrapper{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column !important;
    width:18rem;
    background:#0A2463;
  }  

.links:hover::after{
  content:"»";
  font-size:2.5rem;
  }
  
#nav_check:not(:checked) ~ menu {
    display:none;
  }
  
.navBar > #nav_check:checked ~ .menu {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }
  
  
  
}/*closing bracket for media query*/
```

```html
<div class="navBar">
  <input type="checkbox" id="nav_check">
  <div class="nav_btn">
    <label for="nav_check" class="hamburgerLines" id="nav_icon">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
   <div class="menu_textWrapper"> 
    <div class="nav_links">
      <a href="#about" class="links">About</a>
      <a href="#projects" class="links">Projects</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="links">Contact</a>
      <a href="/resume.pdf" target="_blank"><span class="resume">Resume</span></a>
    </div>
  </div>   
 </div>   
</div>
```

please use:

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('a'), function(el) {
   // whatever with the current node
});
```

Comment: you cant use `.` css selector with `getElementsByClassName` like this `getElementsByClassName('.links')`

Comment: oh no ! tnx bro